# How to close main window of uwp programmatically

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop, uwp-navigation

Unlike wpf, uwp apps can't close their mainpage programatically. `Window.Current.Close()` fails when executed on mainpage of the app. What is the correct way of closing the mainpage in uwp??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryConsolidateAsync()` in main window, closes it properly as if you have closed it by clicking close button in title bar. If app has only one window per instance this is preferred over `Application.Exit()` as this method suspends the app while `Application.Exit()` closes app abruptly. Also closing app by this method your app's previous position and size is remembered unlike for `Application.Exit()`.